# How to check if specific word present in nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a text input and send button for submitting the text that I have entered in input field. I have used react-mention library for hashtags. Now when user is entering text and if user type "#" then it shows available hashtags from data. I want to add a functionality, if hashtag is not present in data then I want to add that hashtag dynamically and make api call.

Hashtag data looks like:

```js
const hashtagData = [
  { id: 0, display: "end" },
  { id: 1, display: "start" },
];
```

Once user has selected the preregistered hashtag and writing his own hashtag, text will look like:

```
"sample text for already present hashtag #end and manually entered #newHashtag
```

Inside my onclick function of submit button, I've written this logic for checking newly entered hashtag:

```js
let array = [];
newComment.split(" ").map((word) => {
  array.push(word.split("#")[1]);
});
var r = hashtagData.some((i) => i.display.includes(array.map((j) => j)));
console.log(r);
```

I am not sure if I am doing it right, what is mistake in my code and should I put this logic in onClick or in onChange method?

Comment: *"...what is mistake in my code..."* What problem are you having with it? (Although note that `.map((j) => j)` doesn't do anything useful, and `includes` expects a string, not an array, so will convert the array to string -- which isn't helpful here.)

Comment: I am not sure, if I have to check for newly entered hashtags in onclick or in onchange method

Comment: `word.split("#")[1]` fails if the word does not have '#'

Comment: @ProGu - Depends on your definition of "fails". It gives you `undefined`. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder    newComment.split(" ").map(word => (
                word[0] === "#" ? array.push(word.split("#")[1]): array
              )), I can do this for undefined cases

Comment: @SurajPawar - FWIW, I would strongly encourage you not to abuse the conditional operator that way, and not to misuse `map` like that (details on the latter in my answer). Just use an `if`, and if not using the array `map` creates, use `forEach` or a `for-of` loop.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay, I got your point. I will implement the logic,  you have suggested :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `.split(" ")` is sufficient for "words" for your purposes, then what you have isn't too far off. Some notes:

- It's misleading to use `map` if you aren't using the array it creates (more in [my blog post about it](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/)).
- `word.split("#")[1]` will give you `undefined` for words that don't have `#` in them, which you probably want to weed out.
- `i.display.includes(array.map((j) => j))` doesn't work for a couple of reasons:

  - `array.map((j) => j)` is pointless, it just creates a copy of the array.
  - `includes` expects a string as its argument, not an array, so will convert the array to a string; that joins together the array entries with commas in-between, which won't match your hashtags.

Instead, something along these lines:

```
const newTags =
    // Split the comment into "words"
    newComment.split(" ")
    // Get the "words" that are hashtags (or `undefined` for ones that aren't)
    .map(word => word.split("#")[1])
    // Filter out the "words" that either A) Are `undefined` or B) Are already known
    // in `hashtagData`
    .filter(word => word !== undefined && !hashtagData.some(tag => tag.display === word));
```

That gives you an array of the new hashtags in the comment (empty if none).

Live Example:

```js
const hashtagData = [
    { id: 0, display: "end" },
    { id: 1, display: "start" },
];
const newComment = "sample text for already present hashtag #end and manually entered #newHashtag";
const newTags =
    // Split the comment into "words"
    newComment.split(" ")
    // Get the "words" that are hashtags (or `undefined` for ones that aren't)
    .map(word => word.split("#")[1])
    // Filter out the "words" that either A) Are `undefined` or B) Are already known
    // in `hashtagData`
    .filter(word => word !== undefined && !hashtagData.some(tag => tag.display === word));
console.log(newTags);
```

If you just need a flag instead, use `some` instead of `filter` at the end:

```
const hasNewTag =
    // Split the comment into "words"
    newComment.split(" ")
    // Get the "words" that are hashtags (or `undefined` for ones that aren't)
    .map(word => word.split("#")[1])
    // See if there's any "word" that is both A) Not `undefined`, and B) Not already
    // known in `hashtagData`
    .some(word => word !== undefined && !hashtagData.some(tag => tag.display === word));
```

Live Example:

```js
const hashtagData = [
    { id: 0, display: "end" },
    { id: 1, display: "start" },
];
const newComment = "sample text for already present hashtag #end and manually entered #newHashtag";
const hasNewTag =
    // Split the comment into "words"
    newComment.split(" ")
    // Get the "words" that are hashtags (or `undefined` for ones that aren't)
    .map(word => word.split("#")[1])
    // See if there's any "word" that is both A) Not `undefined`, and B) Not already
    // known in `hashtagData`
    .some(word => word !== undefined && !hashtagData.some(tag => tag.display === word));
console.log(hasNewTag);
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this will help you but here are the some problems I see here

---

`array.map((j) => j)` is same as `array` just maps the array to itself

---

```
let array = [];
newComment.split(" ").map((word) => {
    array.push(word.split("#")[1]);
});
```

`map` is a transformation function but used here to make a loop
If you want to use `map` properly then do this

```
let array = newComment.split(" ").map(word => word.split("#")[1]);
```

---

`i.display.includes(array.map((j) => j))`
`display` is a string and `array` is an array
You are checking if a string includes an array which doesn't make any sense
I assume what you are trying to do is

```
hashtagData.some(i => array.includes(i.display))
```

Answer (score -1):

You **should** use `Regex`

**Pattern**

```js
([^a-z]+[a-z]*)*
```

Select groups